# ¿Cómo modificar y centrar el slider de un plugin?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, plugin, slider

Tengo un plugin que contiene un slider de equipo, separado por filtros, el problema esta en que el mismo me funciona sin inconvenientes pero al filtrar las opciones no me centran a las personas.

[image: Slider completo]

Al filtrar en un área, simplemente oculta el resto, esto provoca que en el front end a veces no aparezca nadie y se deba hacer scroll hasta la persona, esto podría crear confusiones.

¿De que manera puedo modificar el código para que se centre en una persona?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Añade el codigo con el que estas trabajando, por favor